# Javascript promises + useState + firebase onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I have a database listener in my code and I am trying to get every user's new posts and then (when I have all of them in an array) update the posts state.

My code looks like this but it is not working good, because setPosts is async and sometimes it might be called again before ending the state update. I think that I need to wrap the listener in a Promise but I have no idea how to do it detaching the listener when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { firebase } = props;

    // Realtime database listener
    const unsuscribe = firebase
      .getDatabase()
      .collection("posts")
      .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
      .collection("userPosts")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        changes.forEach(async (change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            // Get the new post
            const newPost = change.doc.data();

            // TODO - Move to flatlist On end reached
            const uri = await firebase
              .getStorage()
              .ref(`photos/${newPost.id}`)
              .getDownloadURL();

            // TODO - Add the new post *(sorted by time)* to the posts list
            setPosts([{ ...newPost, uri }, ...posts]);
          }
        });
      });

    /* Pd: At the first time, this function will get all the user's posts */

    return () => {
      // Detach the listening agent
      unsuscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

Any ideas?

Also, I have think to do:

```
useEffect(() => {

const { firebase } = props;

let postsArray = [];

// Realtime database listener
const unsuscribe = firebase
  .getDatabase()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(firebase.getCurrentUser().uid)
  .collection("userPosts")
  .orderBy("time") // Sorted by date
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(async (change) => {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        // Get the new post
        const newPost = change.doc.data();

        // Add the new post to the posts list
        postsArray.push(newPost);
      }
    });

    setPosts(postsArray.reverse());
  });
```

But in this case, the post uri is saved too in the firestore document (something I can do because I write on the firestore with a cloud function that gets the post from storage), and I don't know if it is a good practice.

Thanks.

### Update

Cloud Function code:

```
exports.validateImageDimensions = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Libraries
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    const sizeOf = require("image-size");
    const url = require("url");
    const https = require("https");
    const sharp = require("sharp");
    const path = require("path");
    const os = require("os");
    const fs = require("fs");

    // Lazy initialization of the Admin SDK
    if (!is_validateImageDimensions_initialized) {
      const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
      admin.initializeApp({
        // ...
      });

      is_validateImageDimensions_initialized = true;
    }

    // Create Storage
    const storage = admin.storage();

    // Create Firestore
    const firestore = admin.firestore();

    // Get the image's owner
    const owner = context.auth.token.uid;

    // Get the image's info
    const { id, description, location, tags } = data;

    // Photos's bucket
    const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket-name");

    // File Path
    const filePath = `photos/${id}`;

    // Get the file
    const file = getFile(filePath);

    // Check if the file is a jpeg image
    const metadata = await file.getMetadata();
    const isJpgImage = metadata[0].contentType === "image/jpeg";

    // Get the file's url
    const fileUrl = await getUrl(file);

    // Get the photo dimensions using the `image-size` library
    getImageFromUrl(fileUrl)
      .then(async (image) => {
        // Check if the image has valid dimensions
        let dimensions = sizeOf(image);
        // Create the associated Firestore's document to the valid images
        if (isJpgImage && hasValidDimensions(dimensions)) {
          // Create a thumbnail for the uploaded image
          const thumbnailPath = await generateThumbnail(filePath);

          // Get the thumbnail
          const thumbnail = getFile(thumbnailPath);

          // Get the thumbnail's url
          const thumbnailUrl = await getUrl(thumbnail);

          try {
            await firestore
              .collection("posts")
              .doc(owner)
              .collection("userPosts")
              .add({
                id,
                uri: fileUrl,
                thumbnailUri: thumbnailUrl, // Useful for progress images
                description,
                location,
                tags,
                date: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                likes: [], // At the first time, when a post is created, zero users has liked it
                comments: [], // Also, there aren't any comments
                width: dimensions.width,
                height: dimensions.height,
              });

            // TODO: Analytics posts counter
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(
              `Error creating the document in 'posts/{owner}/userPosts/' where 'id === ${id}': ${err}`
            );
          }
        } else {
          // Remove the files that are not jpeg images, or whose dimensions are not valid
          try {
            await file.delete();

            console.log(
              `The image '${id}' has been deleted because it has invalid dimensions.
               This may be an attempt to break the security of the app made by the user '${owner}'`
            );
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Error deleting invalid file '${id}': ${err}`);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });

    /* ---------------- AUXILIAR FUNCTIONS  ---------------- */

    function getFile(filePath) {
      /* Get a file from the storage bucket */

      return bucket.file(filePath);
    }

    async function getUrl(file) {
      /* Get the public url of a file  */

      const signedUrls = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: "read",
        expires: "01-01-2100",
      });

      // signedUrls[0] contains the file's public URL
      return signedUrls[0];
    }

    function getImageFromUrl(uri) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = url.parse(uri); // Automatically converted to an ordinary options object.
        const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
          if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
            return reject(new Error("statusCode=" + response.statusCode));
          }
          let chunks = [];
          response.on("data", (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
          });
          response.on("end", () => {
            try {
              chunks = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            } catch (e) {
              reject(e);
            }
            resolve(chunks);
          });
        });

        request.on("error", (e) => {
          reject(e.message);
        });
        // Send the request
        request.end();
      });
    }

    function hasValidDimensions(dimensions) {
      // Posts' valid dimensions
      const validDimensions = [
        {
          width: 1080,
          height: 1080,
        },
        {
          width: 1080,
          height: 1350,
        },
        {
          width: 1080,
          height: 750,
        },
      ];

      return (
        validDimensions.find(
          ({ width, height }) =>
            width === dimensions.width && height === dimensions.height
        ) !== undefined
      );
    }

    async function generateThumbnail(filePath) {
      /* Generate thumbnail for the progressive images */

      // Download file from bucket
      const fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
      const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

      const thumbnailPath = await bucket
        .file(filePath)
        .download({
          destination: tempFilePath,
        })
        .then(() => {
          // Generate a thumbnail using Sharp
          const size = 50;
          const newFileName = `${fileName}_${size}_thumb.jpg`;
          const newFilePath = `thumbnails/${newFileName}`;
          const newFileTemp = path.join(os.tmpdir(), newFileName);
          sharp(tempFilePath)
            .resize(size, null)
            .toFile(newFileTemp, async (_err, info) => {
              // Uploading the thumbnail.
              await bucket.upload(newFileTemp, {
                destination: newFilePath,
              });

              // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the temporal file to free up disk space.
              fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
            });

          // Return the thumbnail's path
          return newFilePath;
        });

      return thumbnailPath;
    }
  });
```

Comment: "it is not working good" is unfortunately hard to help with. When you step through this code in a debugger and set breakpoints, which specific line doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: Updated. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You may want to use rxjs and the delay operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay

Comment: why don't you use a Cloud Functions to set the image path when the post is added to firestore? Thus you don't have to deal with this logic on the client

Comment: Yeah I have done this

Comment: was your problem resolved by using Cloud Functions? If so can you share the the answer with the community?

Comment: I have write the cloud function but doesn't works really fast because I am not handling really good the https.get() method. I have to solve this issue but I'm going to update this question with the cloud function code, as it works fine (but really really slow)